# split string using as separator all characters inside two parenthesis c#

Tags: c#, parsing, split

I have this string

```
string A = "2000 to 2062 (1,2000)";
```

How can i get them separate like this using the parenthesis:

```
string B = "2000 to 2062"; 
string C = "1,2000"
```

Comment: How many do you have like this? Are they all fixed length exactly like this? Can you just split on the `(` and trim the `)` off the end?

Comment: I have many string varibles similar to String A, the only thing that doesnt change are the parenthesis, its not fixed lenght.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split a string on multiple characters, so simply pass in the `'('` and `')'` characters to the `Split` method:

```
string A = "2000 to 2062 (1,2000)";

// Split the string on the parenthesis characters
string[] parts = A.Split('(', ')');

// Get the first part (remove the trailing space with Trim)
string B = parts[0].Trim();

// It's safest to check array length to avoid an IndexOutOfRangeException
string C = parts.Length > 1 ? parts[1].Trim() : string.Empty;

// B = "2000 to 2062" 
// C = "1,2000"
```